# Very slow design view on a complex form with a lot of controls

Tags: vb.net, forms, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-express

Let's start with a confession: I came from a VB6 background, and I'm accustomed to coding within the events of objects on a form, and as such my code for events ends up in somewhat random order in the code window.  With this habit, it's never been very important to remember the names of controls (although I name them well)... I just double click on a button in the design view, which brings me straight to the code for that control's primary event.  If I forget the name of a control, I click it and view properties.  It's not a habit I've moved away from.

Well, now this is catching up to me. Using VS Express 2013, I have a form that contains a HUGE number of containers-within-containers, labels, buttons, and other doohickeys.  I ported my code from VS.NET Express 2008 where this wasn't a problem.  But now the act of selecting any control in the design view takes around 10 seconds before I can view its properties.  If I drag to resize a control, and another 10 seconds passes before I can select another control.  It makes designing this form nearly impractical.

In this particular project, I'm using use a tab control (which is never visible to the user) to design many "screens" which each contain panels full of controls.  The panels for each "screen" are moved out of the tabs and docked into the main form as requested by the user changing screens.  (I'm using the term "screen" to mean a window full of controls, usually maximized.)

Within the same project, a simple modal password-change form isn't slow to edit controls visually, even if the complex form is still visible in the IDE.

My question is in three parts:

***First***, what the heck is it spending all that time doing?

***Second***, is there a setting I can tweak to improve the speed?

***Third***, should I give up on trying to speed it up as-is, and move each "screen" into its own form for design purposes to avoid this slowness?  (It's a lot of work to do that now... see next paragraph.)

Thus far I have avoided separating "screens" onto separate forms because I don't want a new window to come up when users change screens, and because code for the controls in one screen may affect the properties of controls on other screens... In such cases I prefer not to write out

**form.doohickey.text = "blah"**

..but rather keep it as ...

**doohickey.text = "blah"**

I'm using VB but I don't think this question is VB-specific.)

Comment: define *HUGE number of controls*.  It might be simpler to do it straight forward and create logical screens on tabs or perhaps other forms.  What purpose does locating these out of view serve?

Comment: Several hundred... I don't know of a way to count them easily.  As to the purpose of locating them out of view... well, they're not supposed to be in view upon launching the app, so I'm not sure I understand your question.  I will add that my machine has an SSD so if there's disk thrashing going on, this might be much worse without it.

Comment: Anytime, you have so many controls, I would create composite controls with encapsulated functionality. and then just wire them together on the main form, often - dynamically. I would create placeholders and then place these controls there at runtime. remember, if you have deep control hierarchy, you can have painting problems on x64 machines (just a tip)

Comment: Sounds like a UI design issue.  There are going to be some logical partitions in several hundred controls; some stuff might be only optionally needed an better located somewhere else - a Dialog perhaps.   It should be laid out with user convenience in mind and not that you do not like including form references in your code.  I dont think there are many users who would find 200-300 controls flung at them to be a welcome sight.

Comment: "I dont think there are many users who would find 200-300 controls flung at them to be a welcome sight." Hmmm... well, how many objects are in the IDE itself?  Quite a few, I'd say.  Remember they're not all visible at the same time.  It depends a great deal on how it's laid out, and what its purpose is.  Of course these ojects aren't just super-tiny and clumped together.  The text is legible, the flow is logical.

Comment: Respectfully, Plutonix, I'm not prepared to defend my UI and I'm confident users will find it very useful and intuitive for its purpose.

Comment: "how many objects are in the IDE itself" - there is big difference between developers and users. We live in it, they just work 9 to 5

Comment: Seriously folks, my question is fairly straightforward, and it appears I'm being asked to defend my UI, not from the perspective of making development process easier, but from the perspective of the user.  I will just state that (although I am now out of the field) I've worked with large teams of developers, and my UI's have always been highly regarded.  If my software is hard to use, that's on me.  Without seeing it, those who criticize it are, by definition, not qualified to do so.

Comment: *Remember they're not all visible at the same time.*  So, you have a whole bunch of controls, many of them are not needed in this context (form/tab/screen), but you create them there because *I prefer not to write out* form references.  In monolithic things like that it is possible to use maximized-only MDI childen as mega-tabs (and they might have tabs on them as well) so that a whole bunch of controls do not have to be created or painted all at once.

Comment: "I don't want a new window to come up when users change screens" was stated as reason #1, referring to an aspect of that functionality which could confuse a user.  With that said, you may be onto something with maximized-only MDI children.  I have not worked with MDI interfaces since... VB3 and Windows 3.1.  If I understand them correctly, a small [x] will appear under main [X] for the main window.  I will look into this.  I believe there will still be form references, but I never said I would treat my preference as a law I would never break.

Comment: you can kill the title bar and control box so there are for all intents and purposes a Big Tab, a primary purpose being to segment UI controls; either logically or functionally.  There are other kinds of "breaks" in a Document such as Customer -> Driving History -> Vehicle -> Coverage -> Quote.  Well, there are biz rules attached to each tier which might preclude the next from being available.  The deeper you go the less likely that layer will be used in this document and therefore no reason for those controls to be instanced unless/until actually needed (the User might also just bale out).

Comment: Will such an approach diminish the number of objects on a given form in the designer?  Remember, that's what my whole question is about addressing designer slowness.

Comment: Answering my own question (just above, not the main question): Yes.

Comment: Would it help to create smaller user controls and work on each of those separately and then only bring them together in your form at the end. The form would possibly only be for hosting your controls and maybe provide some interaction, but the design of the controls would be done in the user controls which would be kept to a manageable size. Could you do that?

Comment: In response to Plutonix' suggestion, (Thanks) I've been working with MDI interfaces for a while, but don't see a way to eliminate the title bar and control box of a child form as described.  The properties I've modified include: ControlBox= False, FormBorderStyle = None, MaximizeBox=False, MinimizeBox=False, and lastly of course, WindowState=Maximized. With the exception of the aesthetics, this would otherwise be the solution I need.  Anything else needed to make the controlbox invisible when the child form is maximized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now answering my own question.  This is the approach I've ended up using, and it helps a lot...

My overall goal was to have an interface that didn't present a lot of windows, but still presented many different "screens".

I used to place all the different controls of different "screens" on separate panels, which were each contained in separate tabs of an invisible TabControl.  I would then move those panels to my main form as needed by changing their Parent property of each panel as needed.  The only problem with this is that the Winforms designer got ridiculously slow as the number of controls on a form increased into the hundreds.

Now, I am now designing each "screen" as a separate form, each of which contains a panel whose Dock property = Fill.  Such a panel contains everything else on the form.  The form itself never becomes visible.

As needed for to view various screens, I execute:

ScreenForm.Panel1.Parent = Mainform

...or, depending on how I lay it out...

ScreenForm.Panel1.Parent = Mainform.PanelXYZ

...I also either unload or hide any panels which already exist in the panel's new container.

I was GLADLY SURPRISED to find that the code for the various events of the controls contained in the panels would still run, because such code exists in the first form's file, not the displayed form's file.  Luckily, it seems I was wrong.  Event code follows the control itself.  I can copy/paste not only controls, but also their corresponding event code to new forms for easier development and a faster Winforms designer.

All of this is similar to a MDI interface with maximized windows, but no title bar or [X] is displayed.

Essentially I'm doing everything as I did before, except using separate forms with panels instead of separate tabs with panels.  The WinForms designer is much quicker because there aren't so many controls on any form.

Comment: You could use the entire `form` like that but before setting the parent of the form to your "MainForm" you neet to set `form.TopLeve=false` and then `form.Parent = MainForm`

Answer (score 1):

First off, I feel your pain. I have a management section of the application that I'm writing and I'm using a TabControl as well. I have 10 tabs so far and I've only added controls to about 4-5 tabs. I just added up the controls I have and there are about 360 controls so far on this one form and the designer file is ~3300 lines long. Currently anytime I change a property value of one of the controls or go to save the Designer, it takes about 3-4 seconds each time. I have a fairly decent machine; i5-3320M, 8GB RAM, intel 330 SSD, and it still takes a bit for it to do things within the tabControl. It also takes FOREVER to open and load the designer on that form...

What I've found is that it is easier to open a new instance of Visual Studio, create a test application, add a TabControl with the same properties, and design a new tab page from there. When I'm done I do a copy-paste into my actual project. This works great except for the few custom controls I've written in my main application project, I just have to sit and wait while adding them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I accidently found a workaround for saving a lot of time when changing the name of a control on a overpopulated container/project. Before you change the name, toggle False/True the "Generate Member" property of the control you want to rename(I believe you can also locate this under the "Name" property). This adds a few more clicks to the procedure but saves a lot of time. My not-yet-finished project has over 4000 controls and multiple forms and some of them are very "heavy" (10 - 20 seconds to normally change the name of a control). This, of course, don't help in anyway with the loading time of the project (about 35 seconds for me) but I can live with it. Let me know if this works for you too.